# ASP.NET MVC error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, shopping-cart, hidden, ambiguity, ambiguous-call

I have a problem.
In my View of a product I have a button to add it to cart which looks like this:

```
<div>
<% using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {%>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id_produktu) %>
    <%: Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj do koszyka" />
    <% } %>
    <h4><%: Model.cena_produktu.ToString("c")%></h4>
```

For this line:

```
<%: Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery) %>
```

I get an error:

*The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc.TextInputExtensions.Hidden(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, object)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.Hidden(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, object)'*

How to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three ways:

1. Fully qualify the method:

   ```
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.Hidden(Html, "returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
   ```
2. Make your own static method with a different name that obfuscates the name.

   ```
   public static string TheHiddenIWant(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object value)
   {
       return System.Web.Mvc.Html.Hidden(helper, name, value);
   }
   Html.TheHiddenIWant("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
   ```
3. Don't include the reference or using statement for the extension method you don't want. For
   example, get rid of `using System.Web.Mvc.TextInputExtensions`, or just get rid of the reference.

Comment: The first way (slightly changed: `<%: System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.Hidden(Html, "returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery) %>`) helped, thank you! :)